# Android Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android

this error is my very big problem and i read more and more solution about that, but i can't resolve that, i have some fragment on activity and i replace fragments by this code :

```
if (mSelectedMenuItem != 2) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            transaction.replace(R.id.menu_containers, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }, duration);
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

and my `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Bug in android version > 11
    //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("selectedMenuItem", selectedMenuItem);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    selectedMenuItem = savedInstanceState.getInt("selectedMenuItem");
}
```

Comment: Check this [Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for trouble using `postDelayed()`. The App could be killed before this is executed:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
```

Use *can* use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` ( to avoid the IllegalStateException error) but only as a last resort. The only difference between calling `commit()` and `commitAllowingStateLoss()` is that the latter will not throw an exception if state loss occurs. Usually you don’t want to use this method because it implies that there is a possibility that state loss could happen. The better solution, of course, is to write your application so that `commit()` is guaranteed to be called before the activity’s state has been saved, as this will result in a better user experience. Unless the possibility of state loss can’t be avoided, `commitAllowingStateLoss()` should not be used.